# How to use map inside subscribe rxjs6

Tags: rxjs, angular6, rxjs6

I have a service which returns an Observable, after getting the response I map the response and assign result to the array.

```
  this.dataService.fetchData().subscribe(response =>{
    [...this.DataMappingField ]=  response.map(({ ID: id, Name: name }) => ({ id, name }));
  });
```

With spread operators inside subscribe I am getting the error below.

**Error: Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Modelclass'.**

Response from service

```
[
  {ID: 6197, Name: 'A', desc: null,catergory:'lap'},
  {ID: 6198, Name: 'B', desc: null,catergory:'lap'}
]
```

In service, `fetchData` method:

```
fetchData(): Observable<Modelclass> {
  return this.http
    .get<Modelclass>(REQUEST_URL)
    .pipe(
      tap(response => response)
    );
}
```

Model class:

```
export class Modelclass {
  ID: any;
  Name: string;
}
```

---

But the below code is working fine when call with method:

```
this.dataService.fetchData().subscribe(this.fetchResponse);

private fetchResponse(response): void => {
  [...this.DataMappingField ]= response.map(({ ID: id, Name: name }) => ({ id, name }));
}
```

Comment: You already use `map` in subscribe. Which issue yo have?

Comment: @but which is not working getting below  Error: Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Modelclass'.'but which is working in below code `this.dataService.fetchData().subscribe(this.fetchResponse);

    private fetchResponse(response): void => {
       [...this.DataMappingField ]=  response.map(({ ID: id, Name: name }) => ({ id, name }));
    }  ` .. so which is not working in subscribe

Comment: did you try ......... .subscribe((response: any) => { // here your code //});

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is incorrect response typing. The definition of `fetchData` method should be like this:

```
fetchData(): Observable<Modelclass[]> {
  return this.http
    .get<Modelclass[]>(REQUEST_URL)
    .pipe(
      tap(response => response)
    );
}
```

Note I am using **`Modelclass[]`** as a response type.